# onclick radio button disable datepicker

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

I want to disable datepicker when clicking on radio button

```
<input 
  type="radio" 
  class="shwbtnrd" 
  required="required" 
  id="bookType" 
  name="bookType" 
  value="1" 
  checked="checked" 
  onclick="window.location='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';" 
/>

<input 
  name="dat" 
  id="dat" 
  required="required" 
  readonly="readonly" 
  placeholder="Date of Birth" 
  class="form-control"  
  type="text"  
/>

<script>
$(function () {
  $("#dat").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-100:+0',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: new Date()
  });
});
</script>
```

If i click on radio button then need to disable bootstrap datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to disable datepicker for input type

```
$("#dat").attr("disabled", true);
```

where **dat** is **id** of input type.

This code is working for me.